# Python Error name 'runfile' is not defined in Spyder

Tags: python-2.7

I get error: name 'runfile' is not defined in Spyder (Python 2.7) although I have change my working directory where I save my scripts. I just run the code in command line, but I want run it in Spyder. How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There probably are multiple things that could be causing this.  I ran into this issue and what was causing it for me was an issue with sitecustomize.  After searching for a solution (details from my search here: [Spyder 'runfile' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250361/spyder-runfile-is-not-defined/38254636)), I essentially needed to go to a command prompt (cmd in Windows) and type:

```
spyder --reset
spyder --default
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the cause of the issue is that spyder (3.0.0b7 in my case) fails to load the following file (the path is OSX path)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py

So when the above file is failed to load, the following function "runfile" from *sitecustomize.py* got failed to load as well.

```
def runfile(filename, args=None, wdir=None, namespace=None, post_mortem=False):
    """
    Run filename
    args: command line arguments (string)
    wdir: working directory
    post_mortem: boolean, whether to enter post-mortem mode on error
    """
    try:
        filename = filename.decode('utf-8')
    except (UnicodeError, TypeError, AttributeError):
    # UnicodeError, TypeError --> eventually raised in Python 2
    # AttributeError --> systematically raised in Python 3
    .
    .
    .
```

Thus, python not finding the function runfile which is needed to run the .py file inside the spyder IDE and spew out **"NameError: name 'runfile' is not defined"**

The fix for me is to add that path into the PYTHONPATH manager as follow

[image]

My spyder installation is a standalone and not part of the Anaconda package since I don't want to have another python installation on top of 2.x and 3.x python installation. Maybe, that's why *spyder --reset* and *spyder --default* to set them back to default does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows machine in an Anaconda environment, I had to run

`conda update setuptools`

from the command line, as per https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2812.
That seemed to clean things up for me.