# Spyder 'runfile' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to run a script in `Spyder`, but am getting the following error:

```
NameError: name 'runfile' is not defined.
```

I tried a variety of things, like updating the PYTHONPATH variable, but nothing seems to be helping.
I have Python 2.7, Anaconda 2.4, and Spyder 2.3.8.  I have my PYTHONPATH set to:

```
C:\anaconda\\...\externalshell
```

Answer (score 1):

The source of this was an issue with the import of sitecustomize.  This was apparent when you clicked on All Programs>Anaconda>Anaconda Prompt in the Windows Start Menu.  This entry offered some insight with that: [How to reset Spyder IDE (Python 2.7) graphic user interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034114/how-to-reset-spyder-ide-python-2-7-graphic-user-interface)

Essentially, go to a command prompt (cmd in Windows) and type the following:

```
spyder --reset
spyder --default
```

This resolved the underlying sitecustomize issue, which fixed the 'runfile' is not defined error.