# name 'runfile' is not defined error in window

Tags: python, spyder

my code can not run given some error

```
runfile('C:/Users/Rj13/.spyder-py3/untitled02.py', wdir='C:/Users/Rj13/.spyder-py3')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Rj13/.spyder-py3/untitled02.py', wdir='C:/Users/Rj13/.spyder-py3')
>
> NameError: name 'runfile' is not defined

Comment: Can you give more context? Are you typing this somewhere? Or are you pressing something like F5 in Spyder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Error name 'runfile' is not defined in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846953/python-error-name-runfile-is-not-defined-in-spyder)